# Culture-specific XAML workflows in Windows Workflow 4.0

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, culture

I've created a simple XAML workflow with a single InArgument with a default value of 1.234. If I then switch my machine to French(France) in Regional and Lanaguage Options and try to load the workflow into the VS design view, I get the error:

'Failed to create a 'InArgument' from the text '1.234'.'

Looking at the XAML I can see that the attribute this:Activity1.arg1="1.234", which is causing the problem. I then tried creating an equivalent XAML workflow from scratch using VS whilst still running under French settings, and the resulting XAML is different - the attribute is this:Activity1.arg1="[1.234]".

This is causing me two problems:

1) Our end users will not be able to send XAML files to other users running under different regional settings

2) The two XAML files deserialise to different object graphs - in the first case I end up with a Literal and in the second case I get a VisualBasicValue. I then need to code around the differences when I am manipulating the workflow programmatically.

Is there some simple way to avoid this by ensuring that the XAML is always written/read in a neutral culture?

Answer (score 3):

You can programatically change the [Thread.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) to the invariant culture. This can be done temporarily, while the workflow is being loaded.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but it isn't a very good workaround because clients could still create workflows using Visual Studio whilst running in a non-invariant culture.